# Can I stop .DS_Store files being created in certain folders?

Tags: finder

Can I stop .DS_Store files being created in certain folders (and ideally their subfolders)? For instance, in a web development project directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing but for git, then I found gitignore

Comment: I know it can be done system wide but I haven't seen anything about just preventing them on specific, non-network, drives or folders.  Do you want to disable their creation for the entire system?